# Inequality with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Could anyone help me to prove this inequality?
$$ 
\vert e^{-m} - e^{-n}\vert\leq \vert m - n\vert e^{-\min\left\lbrace m,n\right\rbrace} \qquad \mbox{ for all } m,n\geq 0
$$
I don't know how to start.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, $m>n$.

$$e^{-n}-e^{-m}=e^{-n}\left(1-e^{n-m}\right)<e^{-n}(m-n)$$

because $e^{t}\le1+t.$